# Symbols as optional character in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently here's how I do my regex:

```
var myPassword = $('#reg_password').val();
if (myPassword.match(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/)) {}
```

From the regex above, myPassword should contain at least 1 digit, 1 upper case and lower case. Now I want to add symbols as optional. I tried adding

```
([@$!%*#?&]?)
```

at various places in my regex above but it doesn't work...

Comment: you can simply add the symbols in the `[0-9a-zA-Z]` like this: 
`/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/`

Comment: @MariaDeleva: You should make that an actual answer, I think ^^

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to put everything in a single regex. Just test your requirements separately!

```
if (myPassword.length >= 8 &&
    /[a-z]/.test(myPassword) &&
    /[A-Z]/.test(myPassword) &&
    /\d/.test(myPassword) &&
    /[@$!%*#?&]/.test(myPassword)) {
}
```

Comment: I would check for the length first to avoid costly useless checks if the length is less than 8

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: Useless? Yes. Costly? No. :-)

Comment: I meant costly in comparison to the length check

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the symbols in the `[0-9a-zA-Z]` like this:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/
```